# Using `cy.request()` command how to get `meta` tag and `script` tag contents

Tags: javascript, cypress

Using `cy.request()` command how to get `meta` tag and `script` tag content. Example given below:

```
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="og-title" property="og:title" content="Blue zone booking area">

<script data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="nuxt-jsonld-6378ffa8" type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"WebPage","headline":"Parcel area for Blue Zone one","url":"https://staging.booking.com/au/booking-area/zone/blue/"}</script>
```

I have tried cy.wrap($meta) and iterate but it doesn't work ?. Can anyone suggest how can we grab content="Blue zone booking area" attribute from meta tag and headline attribute content from the script tag ?

note : *This is not a front end test, that's why I am using `cy.request()` to make sure that the SEO/SSR are looking good in our website. As google SEO send a request and hit the above url, so then we should make sure that the rendering are looking good. When you use cy.visit() or cy.get() command it will enable the browser javascript and that is not I want*

```
 cy.request(apiHelper.makeGeneralRequestObject("au/booking-area/zone/blue/")).then(
        (response) => {
          const htmlString = response.body;
          const parser = new DOMParser();
          const parseHtml = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');
         const $meta = parseHtml.getElementsByTagName('meta');
        $meta.each(($elem)=>{
        // how to get at here             
      })
    });
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you're fetching a web page and then converting its source code, instead of just... making cypress visit that web page so you can then do whatever you need to do? That's kind of it's whole thing, it can load web pages, in a browser context, so you can then run code against that webpage, from user interactions to page inspection.

Comment: Will explain a bit.  Our website works in 3 countries. Contents are diff for 3 countries. Need to make sure Server Side Rendering with nuxt js are properly working and not based on any UI action.

Comment: We had issues in seo side, as google seo hits the desired url so we need to make sure that the SSR rendering is properly happening. When you use cy.visit() or cy.get() command it will enable the browser javascript and that is not i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing up Cypress/jQuery style with DOM (native) style queries.

This should do it using the DOM parser

```js
cy.request({
  url: 'https://www.booking.com/au',
  failOnStatusCode: false
}).then(response => {
  
  const parser = new DOMParser()
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(response.body, 'text/html')
  
  const metaTags = doc.head.querySelectorAll('meta') // pull <meta> from document head

  metaTags.forEach(metaTag => {      // it's a DOMList, use forEach()
    const key = metaTag.name         // not all have a "name"  
    const content = metaTag.content  // all will have content
    console.log(key, content)
  })
})
```

Or with Cypress (arguably better if performing SEO)

```js
cy.visit('https://www.booking.com/au')
cy.document().then(doc => {
  cy.wrap(doc.head).find('meta').each($meta => {
    const key = $meta.attr('name')
    const content = $meta.attr('content')
    console.log(key, content)
  })
})
```

---

Also consider [Bahmutov - Cypress Lighthouse Example](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-lighthouse/). There is a SEO section in Lighthouse, and the results for `https://www.booking.com/au` currently show

> No `<meta name="viewport">` tag found

[image]

---

**jsonLD**

There is an example of jsonLD test here [cypress-automated-test-for-seo-data](https://github.com/dimitriharding/cypress-automated-test-for-seo-data/blob/7e405d5ec256f55ac39d99a75bd2be6bd756dbfe/cypress/integration/seo-data-tests/seo.spec.js)

```js
it("Verify jsonLD structured data - simple", () => {
  // Query the script tag with type application/ld+json
  cy.get("script[type='application/ld+json']").then((scriptTag) => {
    // we need to parse the JSON LD from text to a JSON to easily test it
    const jsonLD = JSON.parse(scriptTag.text());

    // once parsed we can easily test for different data points
    expect(jsonLD["@context"]).equal("https://schema.org");
    expect(jsonLD.author).length(2);

    // Cross referencing SEO data between the page title and the headline
    // in the jsonLD data, great for dynamic data
    cy.title().then((currentPageTitle) =>
      expect(jsonLD["headline"]).equal(currentPageTitle)
    )
  })
})
```

Comment: Excellent Fody, this was the one I was looking for , Great help ! I am happy that someone understand the req

Comment: Will try this one soon and update !

Comment: So you are saying that I should recommend using cy.visit() for SEO instead of cy.request() ?

Comment: As my tech person advises that cy.visit used browser javascript to perform SSR rendering, but for google SEO as it send request to the url endpoint , so cy.request should be ideal and in that case we should know if the page rendering happens successfully !

Comment: My thoughts are - (1) the meta tags are probably not affected by javascript, so expect those to be the same either way. (2) using Nuxt in SSR mode, technically there should not be any JS fetches that change the DOM, that's the purpose of SSR, to provide all content on first load as the search engine does not wait for secondary loads. Maybe that's what you want to test for, that all content is provided on first load. In that case, you could `cy.visit()` and then `cy.request()` and compare the two results.

Comment: I was also wondering about hydration see [Nuxt - Server side rendering](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/server-side-rendering/) ***the client's JavaScript bundle takes over which then allows the Vue.js app to hydrate***.

Comment: One last thing, how can we get the json-Ids from script tag  <script data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="nuxt-jsonld-6378ffa8" type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"WebPage","headline":"Booking Zone,"url":"https:/booking-area.com/au/zone/blue/"}</script>

Comment: Sorry forget to add that to the question ...